# Threads not terminating on Linux but on Mac

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost

I'm currently working on a genetic algorithm where a new population is computed with different independent threads. My program works fine on OSX but some threads do not terminate on a Linux machine.

I have the following method which each thread performs until I have enough individuals generated. I'm using a single mutex which is part of the population class (as this method is). Therefore the mutex object is not static. The method gets passed a set of `parents` of which it may select one on the first `parents_max`'s parents to generate a new child. A child is generated by mutation or recombination which another parent object. Inside `select_randomly` and `bool_with_prob` I use several distributions from `<random>` (all local variables) to pick a random parent or provide me with a random bool.

I searched the internet for reasons why the threads won't terminate and added serveral (possibly unecessary) locks around method which use `std::random_device` or `std::mt19937` objects.

```
void generate_childs(std::set<individual> &parents, double mutation_rate, size_t parents_max)
{

size_t individuals_size;

{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
    individuals_size = individuals.size();
}

auto selectable_parents_end = parents.begin();
std::advance(selectable_parents_end, parents_max);

while(individuals_size < size)
{
    mutex.lock();
    individual male = *utilities::container::select_randomly(parents.begin(), selectable_parents_end);
    bool generate_child = utilities::container::bool_with_prob(0.3);
    mutex.unlock();

    boost::optional<individual> ind;

    if(generate_child)
    {
        mutex.lock();
        individual female = *utilities::container::select_randomly(parents.begin(), parents.end());
        mutex.unlock();

        ind = mutation::combined_mutated_child(male, female, mutation_rate);
    } else
    {
        ind = mutation::mutated_child(male, 0.9);
    }

    if(ind && ind->is_valid())
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);

        if (individuals.size() < size) {
            individuals.insert(*ind);
        }

    }

    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
        individuals_size = individuals.size();
    }
}
}
```

I'm starting the threads like this:

```
unsigned int number_of_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

auto parents = individuals;

std::vector<boost::thread> threads;

for(size_t i = 0; i<number_of_threads; i++)
{
    threads.emplace_back(&population::generate_childs,
                         this,
                         std::ref(parents),
                         mutation_rate,
                         parents_max);
}

for(auto &t: threads)
{
    t.join();
    std::cout << "Thread finished" << individuals.size()  << std::endl;
}
```

When executing my program on the local (OSX) machine compiled with Clang it performs as expected. On my Linux machine, it does not finish. I even tried to set `number_of_threads=1`, which did not help. When the program is not terminating on my Linux machine I can not quit it with `Ctrl+C`. Any ideas where I might have a race condition or a deadlock?

**EDIT**

As suggested I printed out an comment with the thread id for each thread. Apparently, my usage of the lock when updating the size was inappropriate. Therefore I modified the last lock as follows:

```
std::cout << i << " updating size" << std::endl;

{
    std::cout << i << " updating size about to lock" << std::endl;
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(configuration::mutex);

    std::cout << i << " updating size about to locked" << std::endl;

    individuals_size = individuals.size();

    if(individuals_size >= size)
    {
        std::cout << i << " returning" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

The output of my program is this (skipped the part where threads worked fine):

```
0 started
2 started
3 started
3 entered while
0 entered while
1 started
2 entered while
1 entered while
3 got male 1
0 got male 0
3 got female
2 got male 1
1 got male 1
2 got female
1 got female
0 got mutated
0 before is valid
0 inserting
0 inserted
0 updating size
0 updating size about to lock
0 updating size about to locked
0 returning
Thread finished10
2 got combined
2 before is valid
2 inserting
2 inserted
2 updating size
2 updating size about to lock
2 updating size about to locked
2 returning
```

After this, I don't get any additional outputs. For me, it seems like the lock guard does not free the mutex. Is it the order in which I join the threads? Because I try to join thread 1 before 2 even though it is not finished yet?

Comment: First thing to do is figure out where your threads are stuck at.  Are they blocked on some particular line, or are they moving forward but stuck in some sort of endless loop?  You can figure that out using a debugger, or by adding some temporary `printf()`'s and seeing what does (and does not) get printed.  Once you know *where* the threads are stuck at, you can start thinking about *why* they might be stuck there.

Comment: It''lll be easy when you give us a [mcve]. This is close but, make it complete please.

Comment: I updated my question with some additional outputs. Thank you all for the comments!

Comment: Still not an [mcve]. It's not a program. Please click on the link provided and read the instructions.

Comment: In the example there is not code that outputs "3 entered while", etc.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I don't like in your code is that you misuse locks. For example when you retrieve the size of the container you cannot be sure that the size you've just retrieved is correct right after you unlock the mutex. So the correct pattern could be to lock the block of code where you retrieve the size and work with the container in the assumption that this size is correct -- and unlock it when you don't need this container anymore.

So you should rework the code because there could be race conditions in many places. One possible answer to your question, look at the code below:

```
    mutex.lock();
    individual male = *utilities::container::select_randomly(parents.begin(), selectable_parents_end);
    bool generate_child = utilities::container::bool_with_prob(0.3);
    mutex.unlock();
```

What is an exception is thrown in the `select_randomly`? You would never unlock the mutex and this is a deadlock condition. Why could it throw an exception? For example because the value `selectable_parents_end` have become obsolete due to the race condition.

Comment: _"For example you do not need to lock before retrieving the size of the container if the only thing you need is it's size"_ [citation needed] No standard containers are thread-safe. Doesn't matter what you're doing with them.

Comment: Ok, I agree that the containers are not thread-safe, but my point was: you get a value that is not true when you start using it. This is a little better than just selecting a random value.

Comment: I don't remark on the rest of your answer, but the suggestion that you "don't need locks" to read the size of a container is completely wrong and quite dangerous. Not only are `int`s (or `std::size_t`s, or whatever) not atomic, but you assume implementation details. _Code to spec_, not to assumptions about implementation.

Comment: I found the problem. Your answer helped a lot. I was not getting an exception inside a function but I accessed some I/O from two threads simultaneously. This caused some strange behavior.